# How to Check Path is existing or not in java?

Tags: java, file-io

I have a java program which take path as argument. I want to check whether given path is existing or not before doing other validation. Eg: If i give a path D:\Log\Sample which is not not exist, it has to throw filenotfound exception. How can i do that?

Comment: For Java 7+, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15571496/how-to-check-if-a-folder-exists) is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 28):

```
if (!new File("D:\\Log\\Sample").exists())
{
   throw new FileNotFoundException("Yikes!");
}
```

Besides [`File.exists()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists()), there are also [`File.isDirectory()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory()) and [`File.isFile()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isFile()).

Comment: Please - `throw new FileNotFoundException(f.getAbsolutePath())`

Answer (score 12):

The class java.io.File can take care of that for you:

```
File f = new File("....");
if (!f.exists()) {
    // The directory does not exist.
    ...
} else if (!f.isDirectory()) {
    // It is not a directory (i.e. it is a file).
    ... 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

new File( path ).exists().

Read the javadoc its very useful and often gives many useful examples.

Comment: While I know its meant to be helpful, I find comments like "go read the docs" counter productive.   Don't assume the reader knows what javadocs is or how to access them