# In Java, how do I check if something is a directory, and if not, throw an exception?

Tags: java, exception, directory

I've created this new object:

```
File dir = new File(userHome + "//data")
```

In another class, I want verify that 'dir' is a directory and if it isn't, throw an IllegalArgumentException.

My goal is to then locate specific file types in that directory (if a directory) and process them.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15571496/how-to-check-if-a-folder-exists

Comment: use the keyword throw

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
File f = new File("/Path/To/File/or/Directory");
if (f.exists() && f.isDirectory()) {
   ...
}else{
   throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new File(path).isDirectory();
```

This will return true if the File is a Directory.

```
File dir = new File(userHome + "//data");
if(dir.isDirectory()){
   //store files in an array of File
   fileArray = dir.listFiles();
}
else 
 //do whatever you want
```