# How to check if a directory exist based on the path java

Tags: java

For example I have a path named ’logs/results.log’. the 'results.log' is a file. I want to know whether the directory in the file path exist. Note that the file path is a string.

Note: I want to check whether the directory contained in the given path is existed. For my example I want to check whether the 'logs/' is a directory but not whether the 'logs/results.log' is a directory. One of my confusion is about whether the directory is 'logs' or 'logs/'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a folder exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15571496/how-to-check-if-a-folder-exists)

Comment: No, what I want to asked is whether the directory contained in the path is exist. For example, I have file path  ’logs/results.log’ and I want to know whether the  ’logs/’ is a valid directory. The question given only check whether the given String is a path or directory if I understand it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Files.isDirectory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#isDirectory-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.LinkOption...-):

```
private static boolean dirExists(String file) {
    Path parent = Paths.get(file).getParent();
    return parent != null && Files.isDirectory(parent);
}
```

Usage:

```
System.out.println(dirExists("logs/results.log"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
File file = new File("logs/results.log");

if (file.exists() && file.getParentFile() != null && file.getParentFile().isDirectory()) {
    System.out.println("Parent file is a directory.");
}
```

Comment: `file.getParentFile()` may return `null`. You will get NPE.

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov Yes you're right. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Using java.nio.file.Files:

```
Path path = logs/result.log;

if (Files.exists(path)) {
// ...
}
```